# SQL Server 2016 - Batch select and insert data between tables

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2016

I've been tasked to copy data between 2 tables, and since the smaller set is 40mln records (being the biggest almost 100 times bigger), I'm trying to break the set in smaller batches.

At the end of my test I will put the logic in an SSIS task but so far I can't manage to make to while loop.. well to loop, it writes the first batch and then it exits.

My table has a PK I'm using for the order and offset function but with the filter, the IDs returned are not consecutive so I'm not sure the paging function is correctly working.

The statement is something like that:

```
DECLARE @RowsProcessed int = 0;
DECLARE @Batch int = 100000;
DECLARE @RowCount int = 1;
DECLARE @String AS INT = 13

WHILE @RowCount!= 0
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON
INSERT INTO Table1
    (
... )
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
        Table2
    WHERE
    Filter1 = @String
ORDER BY
    ID
OFFSET @RowsProcessed ROWS 
FETCH NEXT @Batch ROWS ONLY
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF
SET @RowCount =  @@ROWCOUNT
PRINT @RowCount 
SET @RowsProcessed += @Batch
END'
```

My idea is to READ the data in chunks because the source table is really huge and I would like to limit problems with the tempdb but I can't manage to find a way to solve the non consecutive ids problem, unless using a CTE and a RANK OVER but this I think will require to scan all the table, am I wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion,
Ren

Comment: `SET @RowCount =  @@ROWCOUNT` needs to be before immediately following the insert, before `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF`.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do: You have two tables BigTable, (~4 billion rows), and SmallTable, (~40 mil rows). You then want to copy data from the small table to the big table? Are the table structure the same?

Comment: You may find `OFFSET/FETCH` doesn't perform very well anyway. Look into [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Answer (score 0):

> `SET @RowCount =  @@ROWCOUNT` needs to be earlier, immediately following the insert, before `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF`

Thanks a lot @Charlieface I didn't know that the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` could disturb the Rowcount variable.
Really thanks!

As for @NielsBerglund: I need to copy sets of non ordered filtered data from the big table to the small one (probably using the logic above in an SSIS). In the end I will copy all the table with some modification to some special type of rows. I was trying to find a way not to select 40bln records in a single transaction and the OFFSET FETCH seemed to me the best way to achieve it.

Thanks again,